# TCP call flow in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

I am trying to get the TCP call flow inside the Linux Kernel with a version 3.8 for different user space APIs such as connect, bind, listen and accept. Can anyone provide me with a flowchart for flow calls? I was able to find for data flow using send and recv APIs.

Another question, when a client connects to a server, the server creates a new socket to that client for that specific connection returned by the `accept` API. My question does the Linux Kernel maintain any relation between the listening socket and the socket derived from it in some hash bind table or not?

Comment: this is a great question, I'm interested in the answer as well

Comment: Rs your second question, there's no reason why it should. Once accepted. The sockets are independent.

Comment: If you very much interested in call flow, I suggest to use some tool like systemtap, ftrace for understanding the code flow. For ftrace http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.com/2014/05/ftrace-kernel-function-tracer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st question:

http://www.danzig.jct.ac.il/tcp-ip-lab/ibm-tutorial/3376c210.html

All the lectures at Haifux are classic:

http://www.haifux.org/lectures/172/netLec.pdf

http://www.haifux.org/lectures/217/netLec5.pdf

And this is from the original author/maintainer in linux networking himself:

http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html

http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/tcp_output.html

http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/tcp_skbcb.html

2nd question:   Yes, all existing connections are maintained in a critical table:   tcp_hashinfo.  Its' memory address can be read from /proc/kallsyms.   "critical" because reading from it requires locking, so don't try walking the table even though you have the address.   Use globally exported symbols like "inet_lookup_listener" or "inet_lookup_established" to walk the table instead.

More info here:

[How to identify a specific socket between User Space and Kernel Space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835104/how-to-identify-a-specific-socket-between-user-space-and-kernel-space/28821890#28821890)

Answer (score 0):

Flowcharts?  Flow diagrams?  Not a chance.  We would love to have them, but they do not exist but you can review the code; patches happily reviewed.

A socket returns a file descriptor; the process file descriptor table maintains the association between the socket and the other kernel data structures.  The file descriptor makes this a simple array indexing operation, no hashing needed.